# How do you check the efficiency of a python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check how efficient my code is (time taken to run, and lines of code).

For example, how can I check whether this fibonacci code is efficient?

```
def fibonacci(start=0, end=10):
a = 0
b = 1

while True:
    if b >= end:
        break
    a, b = b, a+b

    if start <= a <= end:
        print(a)

fibonacci(start=10, end=45)
```

Comment: be careful with the indentation (function body should be shifted right).

Comment: Ultimately, 'efficiency' may be about how well your program compares with others. It's probable that others have written code to do this on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com. You could see how your stacks up.